# Animated NSPopover implementation

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover

Does anyone have any suggestions on implementing an `NSPopover` like in calendar? I know how to implement the actual popover but what I am specifically referring to is the content of the popover, how when you click in add alert for example, a table like element seems to animate and drop down to reveal further data and then collapse. I thought perhaps implementing an `NSOutlineView` and hiding the disclosure triangles or something along those lines.

Does anyone have any suggests? I've posted images of the type of popover content I am referring to.

[image: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/art/wn_popover_2x.png] [image: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/art/wn_popoveraspanel_2x.png]

You'll note that clicking any of the "add" fields initiate a slide down type animation to show further details, and then collapse when moving out of the field.

Comment: There is no `NSPopup` class.

Comment: Are you referring to `NSPopOver`?

Comment: I stand corrected. Yes NSPopOver.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see how using an outline view could possibly simplify the task of achieving any of the layouts you've included as an example given the diversity of items to be displayed (date ranges, check boxes, labels, ..).

Just use labels, text fields, etc. in the `NSPopOver` and place them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Cacau. The suggestion to use an outline view was simply trying to harness it's inbuilt structure. As I'm sure you know, when you expand an outline view, its graphical representation animates and expands down to reveal the tree structure. I am after a similar functionality here where clicking "add invite" for example, will expand to reveal a more detailed form (including labels and text fields etc) where the user can input data.